# Sequelize: Cannot delete 'through' table rows by cascade

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

[In what follows I must admit I probably not using the correct terminology according to sequelize, due to my unfamiliarity with the package]

Hi, I have two tables (A, C) in a n to m relationship 'through' table B

```
A.belongsToMany(C, {
    through: {
        model: B,
    } 
});
C.belongsToMany(A, {
    through: {
        model: B,
    }
});
```

Note that table B has an additional data column which is independent of A and C. Using this system I can successfully create rows in table B (with or without data for the extra column as needed) when ever I create a new row for table A or table B.

But deleting (destroy) rows from A or from C does not cascade to delete the corresponding rows of B. As far as I can tell from the documentation and from other similar problems on this website and others, onDelete: 'cascade' is the default setting. If I try including it anyway in the model, the rows of B still do not delete.

I have noticed one thing which seems weird though. According to the documentation, information about table B should be directly available to me if I have an object representing a row of table A or table C. (For example a.get('B') will return an object representing a row of table B). Performing a.get('B') does return object b, but performing c.get('B') does not. Is this a clue?

Note also, that rows of table B do not delete regardless of whether I am destroying rows of table A or table C

Many thanks